# How to fix Error running '__rvm_make -j8'

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rvm, jruby-openssl

I am having issue in installing ruby 2.7.1

I am getting this error:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/luqman/.rvm/log/1690926841_ruby-2.7.1/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation
```

My log file is full of errors which I can't share over here and I am just sharing the starting and end part of it.

The starting part is:

```
ast.c:115:19: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
    rb_funcall(f, rb_intern("set_encoding"), 2, rb_enc_from_encoding(enc), rb_str_new_cstr("-"));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/ruby/ruby.h:1847:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
./include/ruby/ruby.h:2689:27: note: expanded from macro 'rb_funcall'
        rb_funcallv(recv, mid, \
                          ^~~
./internal.h:2411:54: note: expanded from macro 'rb_funcallv'
        rb_funcallv_with_cc(&rb_funcallv_data, recv, mid, argc, argv); \
                                                     ^~~
ast.c:115:19: note: '{' token is here
    rb_funcall(f, rb_intern("set_encoding"), 2, rb_enc_from_encoding(enc), rb_str_new_cstr("-"));
```

Ending part:

```
linking shared-object socket.bundle
93 warnings generated.
53 warnings generated.
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
13 warnings generated.
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

What steps I have done till now:

- I have reinstalled rvm
- Updated Brew
- Upgraded Brew
- Upgraded OpensSL

I have also tried other solutions from the internet which include

- Adding a specific path of opensSl like: `rvm install 2.7.1  -C --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/bin/openssl`
- Updated Xcode
- 

My Mac version is Ventura 13.2.1

Nothing has worked, I would really appreciate any help in this regard!

Answer (score 7):

I bumped into a similar issue today, part of it is [brew defaulting to openssl 3](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/92d985af3e3757d045d1ce5f0db52ddf1e557108) ([credit](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/issues/409#issuecomment-926745133)):

```bash
brew install openssl@1.1
rvm install ruby-2.7.1 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)
```

and my best guess is that the desired ruby version does not support your os version. try something newer (I had to go above 3.x)

Comment: Already tried it, this didn't work. And my rails version is supported. It was installed earlier and I was using it for a month but somehow crashed now

Answer (score 3):

So this worked for me

`brew reinstall openssl@1.1`
Also check if other openssl versions are installed or not? If so remove them.(like some use openssl@3 which we can configure with our ruby version or vise versa)

`brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl@1.1 --force`
Now I am only installing one openssl and removing the rest

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc   
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
rvm install ruby-2.7.1 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --verify-downloads 1
```

Also this link might also be helpful for some. [rvm make j8 error](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5039)