# Cocoapods installation failed and can't change ruby local version

Tags: ruby, cocoapods, llvm

MacBook Pro, macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Having 2 main issues when trying to install cocoapods, first one I'm getting the error when trying to change the ruby version to 2.7.5, because im able to change it global but not local:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-de-User / % rbenv versions      
  system
* 2.7.5 (set by /Users/user/.rbenv/version)
  mruby-3.0.0

user@MacBook-Pro-de-User / % ruby -v                   
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]

user@MacBook-Pro-de-User / % sudo rbenv local 2.7.5    
Password:
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv-version-file-write: line 19: .ruby-version: Read-only file system
```

the second issue im having is when trying to install cocoapods:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-de-User / % sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20240111-988-w3p1cs.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in `block in try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in `try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:672:in `try_ldflags'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1832:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:9:in `system_libffi_usable?'
    from extconf.rb:46:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.16.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.16.3/gem_make.out
```

mkmf.log:

```
"pkg-config --exists libffi"
| pkg-config --libs libffi
=> "-lffi\n"
"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin19 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib -L. -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64   -lruby.2.6   "
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: note: did not find header 'config.h' in framework 'ruby' (loaded from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

also tried to do brew install cocoapods but it gets stuck at llvm cmake --build ., also if I try to install just llvm:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-de-User /usr % brew install llvm
    Warning: You are using macOS 10.15.
    We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
    It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
    It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
    Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
    Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
    Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
    Do not ask for help from Homebrew or its maintainers on social media.
    You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
    Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
    We will review it but may or may not accept it.
    
    ==> Fetching llvm
    ==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/a656e8d
    ######################################################################### 100.0%
    ==> Downloading https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-1
    Already downloaded: /Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/0f45ee25df06c0fb1fa6d0d6df4677a9487c4b95f1020855dc61f95b532eb9c0--llvm-project-17.0.6.src.tar.xz
    ==> cmake -G Ninja .. -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang;clang-tools-extra;lld;lldb;ml
    ==> cmake --build .
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to my problem here: [Ruby installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76819855/22483352). The issue with cocoapods installation was because of old ruby version (2.6.3), and couldn't change to other version localy probably because I was having an error in the installation even though the version was getting installed. The issue about installation was because of openssl version, it was using 3.0 instead of 1.1 which seems to be the correct one for the installation. Just had to install the 1.1 openssl version and install the ruby version with that openssl version.

```
brew install openssl@1.1
rvm install ruby-3.3.0 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)
```